# I am looking for a replacement for pgsync. Looks like the library is not supported anymore. How to sync between postgresql and elasticsearch?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, indexing, backend, pgsync

Someone from the backend development side, please help with the below.
we have a site driven by Postgres. We also have a elastic search implementation to make filter/searches faster. We needed a framework to sync the indexes between these two. We tried pgsync 'https://github.com/ankane/pgsync/issues' and hit a roadblock, and realised that it's not actively supported anymore.
Could you suggest a tool/framework for syncing between Postgres and elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking at the wrong tool.

- [pgsync](https://github.com/ankane/pgsync) by [ankane](https://github.com/ankane) is a tool for syncing data from one
  Postgres database to another Postgres database.
- [PGSync](https://github.com/toluaina/pgsync) by [toluaina](https://github.com/toluaina) is a tool for syncing data from Postgres to
  Elasticsearch.

I believe you are interested in the latter.